# How to transform an equation to a variable using "solve" in mathcad?

Tags: mathcad

I wanted to know (as the title said) how to transform an equation to a variable using "solve" in mathcad? Because "solve" doesn't work for some reason. I would be grateful if someone could tell how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform `given` block in function`f(parameters)=find(x1, x2, ...)`

[image: example with coubic equation]